# Getting True for all conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

Node js express and I wrote a code to check whether a given product has a cheaper total price with the same title I'm using Mongo DB as the database and I have added a product with the same title 3 times but with different values and only one of those product is cheaper than the rest but still it prints true for other 2 products as well. Is there a way to solve this? Thank you in advance

This is the code I tried with all the variables defined. This code is inside a map function where it takes each product one by one.In the database I haven't saved any attribute as totalPrice.Product is the collection name

```js
const cheaper = await Product.exists({
          title,
          status: 'live',
          totalPrice: { $lt: totalPrice }
        })
          ? false
          : true;
```

- 1st product title-carrots totalPrice-4260  //Must get false as for
  the expected result
- 2st product title-carrots totalPrice-2380 //This product must get
  cheaper as true
- 3rd product title-carrots totalPrice-4410 //Must get false as for the
  expected result

```js
    exports.getProducts = async (req, res, next) => {
      const DEFAULT_QUANTITY = 1;
    
      function calculateTotalPrice(productPrice, deliveryCost, quantity) {
        return productPrice * quantity + deliveryCost;
      }
      try {
        const userEmail = req.user.email;
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: userEmail });
        const isFarmer = user.accessLevel === 'farmer';
        const products = await Product.find({status:'Live'});
        const result = [];
    
        const productDetails = await Promise.all(products.map(async product => {
    
          const farmer = await User.findById(product.farmer);
          const farmerSaleLocation = farmer.farmer.saleLocation;
          const customerLocation = isFarmer ? null : user.customer.slctdLocation;
          
          let deliveryCost = 0;
          let distanceValue=0;
          let distanceNum=0;
          let totalPrice=0;
          let title=product.title;
          if (farmerSaleLocation && customerLocation) {
            // console.log(farmerSaleLocation.longitude)
            try{const distanceResponse = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=${customerLocation.latitude},${customerLocation.longitude}&destinations=${farmerSaleLocation.latitude},${farmerSaleLocation.longitude}&key=${process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`);
            const distanceData = await distanceResponse.json();
            // console.log(distanceData)
            distanceValue = distanceData.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
            distanceNum=parseFloat(distanceValue.replace("Km","").trim());
            deliveryCost =distanceNum* farmer.farmer.deliveryCharge;
            totalPrice=calculateTotalPrice(product.price, deliveryCost, DEFAULT_QUANTITY)
    
            const cheaper = await Product.exists({
              title,
              status: 'live',
              totalPrice: { $lt: totalPrice }
            })
              ? false
              : true;
    
              console.log("Product name  "+title+" delivery Cost "+deliveryCost+" is it cheaper :"+cheaper)
    
             }
            catch(err){
              console.log(err)
            }
           
          }
          
          return {
            _id:product._id,
            price: product.price,
            title: title,
            imageUrl:product.imageUrls[0],
            overallRating: product.overallRating,
            unit:product.unit,
            likes:product.likes,
            deliveryCost: deliveryCost,
            distance:distanceNum,
            totalPrice:totalPrice,
          };
        }));
    
        res.json(productDetails);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error! something is wrong');
      }
    };
```

Comment: The code is correctly written. If you're getting unintended results it must depend on the actual data you get and/or how you're applying this code. Both of these aren't really clear, so no way to actually answer.

Comment: i'm not familiar with that lib, but when your querying products with the same title, i'd expect `Product.exists({ title: title, status:...` not just `{ title, status:...`

Comment: @simon.ro that's just short object notation `{ foo }` is the same as `{ foo: foo }`. It's ES6 syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions

Comment: I updated the above question with the entire code, does it has anything to be changed

Comment: Try separating the ternary operator onto another line so you can log the result of the exists call.